# There is some problem with react-native-communications

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have used react-native-communications. And instead of space "%20" symbol.

I can't any helpful information in documentation of react-native-communications package

```
onTextPress() {
    const { phone, shift } = this.props

    Communications.text(phone, `Your up coming shift is on 
    ${shift}`)
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/anarchicknight/react-native-communications), you have to use `textWithoutEncoding()` method instead of `text()`.

From the author:

> If you are going to use this method please be aware that if you have
>   any text for your message body which needs to be encoded you are
>   responsible for doing this yourself before passing the string to the
>   method.

Comment: Thank you so much. Why I couldn't find this textWithoutEncoding().